# Copy large code block from external source to an answer to "secure" it?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I found [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447668/1469208) to [quite interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13605767/1469208). Answer is step-by-step procedure, which includes using [piece of code, 75 lines long from an external source (Gist)](https://gist.github.com/bmarston/5541632).

Solution works perfectly, but I have doubts about situations, where author changes name of that Gist, deletes it or when link to this external source become invalid by any other reason.

Is it reasonable and acceptable here to copy entire code block to the end of this answer, to "secure" it from situations like above?

Comment: It would appear the the gist owner and the poster of the answer are the same person bmarston

Comment: I don't think this is a problem. We can always add some info, like "_This is a copy of the code [link] mentioned above_". I'm asking here about general rule, not about problems with authors, titles and copyrights. BTW: This is a meta discussion, so you're welcome to fromulate any of your doubts as an answer.

Comment: It wasn't a doubt merely an observation that in this case attribution is not really necessary. In the general case of course it is.

Comment: @trejder: A "general rule" that ignores issues of authors, titles, and copyrights is not a usable rule.

Comment: I suggest leaving a comment on the answer asking the poster to include the code

Comment: @ivarni That will not work in case of authors that hasn't visited site for years. But, as it was already explained, copyrights issues, which I passed over initially, explains everything and "general answer" to my question is "no".

Comment: In this case the author was last online 5 days ago, though, so in for that particular answer commenting would be an option. But yes, the general answer is "no" which is why I suggested pleading the author.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, you can't do that, because you don't have permission to change the license of the code.  Only code licensed under CC BY-SA can be placed into answers, but code with any license can be linked.

Only the author / copyright holder of the code can make it available under a different license.

Comment: "Only the author / copyright holder of the code can make it available under a different license." - why is that? I don't see any particular license associated with that code, hence I believe it can be deduced to be public domain (at least for the time being). Furthermore, many licenses (e.g. MIT) allow re/sub-licensing the code with a different license.

Comment: You can't deduce it to be public domain, apparently, because without an explicit license, any code on GitHub is "all rights reserved". [See here](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2615869/open-source-software/github-needs-to-take-open-source-seriously.html) for an interesting read. I will be emailing GitHub about the default license.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté In nations that are signatories to the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention), any work eligible for copyright is automatically protected by copyright at the time of its creation. The author needs to explicitly disclaim or license their rights. The rule "no copyright notice means no copyright protection" used to be true in the United States decades ago (see the copyright status of [Night of the Living Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Living_Dead#Copyright_status)), but this has not been the case for a long time.

Comment: WOW thanks @ADTC!!  That article is a must read for anyone contributing to a project hosted on github!

Comment: However, you've forgotten to mention, that any copyrighted work can be quoted.

Comment: Yes, while copying all 75 lines of code and just dumping it there is a no-no without license, you can cite the source and make qoutes of interesting bits from it, like 1-2 code lines that are most relevant in the context of the question. I think there is a max % allowed to be quoted, not sure how much though.

Comment: @ADTC: Actually, no you can't even excerpt it on SO.  Fair Use applies to using excerpts in your work, but **Fair Use does not allow you to relicense any of the original code, not even excerpts**.  So I can write a critique on my blog (criticism is a Fair Use), and in that blog post I can use excerpts.  But I cannot then give others permission to use the code contained in my blog post.  They can use that code themselves only if their usage also falls under Fair Use.  In my SO answers, I can't restrict people to only fair usage, I'm forced to license under CC BY-SA.

Comment: @РСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ: You can quote it for certain purposes, but you cannot license the quoted work to others.  So such quotes can't be on SO.

Comment: Thanks ADTC and apsillers for the enlightening knowledge. All this legal stuff is rather complicated and varies from country to country. Too bad we, developers, still have to deal with it.

Comment: @BenVoigt no, there's no need to licence such quotes, because the whole answer would be a derivative work on its own licence.

Comment: @РСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ: The license for a derivative work needs to respect the license for the work it was derived from.  In order to license the entire explanation, quotes and all, under CC BY-SA, it is necessary to have permission to redistribute quotes from the original code under CC BY-SA.  **Fair Use does not include that permission**