# I quoted code from an external site but was probably not allowed to

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142750/java-how-does-ssl-verify-certificate-revocation-status/37144410#37144410).

Since I didn't want to provide a link-only answer I quoted the most important code examples in my answer.

Then I have found [this meta-post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275485/copy-large-code-block-from-external-source-to-an-answer-to-secure-it) and realized my mistake. I have edited the code quotation out but in the revision it is surely still readable.

What can I do? Should I delete my answer instead? I'm so sorry.

Edit:
 The code has an Apache 2.0 licence. The meta-post says it will be posted here under a CC BY-SA licence and I'm not allowed to do that even under "fair use".

Comment: Well I think the problem with your post is you're only referring to links now. What's the licensing problem with that code actually?

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ But he asked for examples of industry security libraries - and I can't quote those, at the moment I'm at a loss. Its an Apache 2.0 licence, not a CC BY-SA licence

Comment: @Rhayene, why do you care so much about all this licensing stuff? I think _no one cares_ about that. And if someone does, he will complain, but since nobody seems to give a ****...

Comment: @ForceBru just because nobody cares, does not mean its actually legal or OK

Comment: Kudos for caring about proper licensing, but your quoting that code may well be fair use: http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/what-is-fair-use/ and it may not even be against the Apache license itself.

Comment: @Rhayene, to my mind, if someone will find this _illegal_ or _not OK_, they will contact you (e.g. write a comment) to express their concerns. Until then you're 'probably' free to do anything with the code if you post correct attribution as well.

Comment: @Pekka but the meta-post says that any code posted here is under the CC BY-SA licence - won't I acting against the SO rules?

Comment: @Shog9 I don't have a idea how to express code "in my own words" without changing it - and then its still - code that is not from myself

Comment: I posted an answer to elaborate on this, @Rhayene. The critical guideline here is to use quotes to support *your* answer, rather than building your answer entirely of quotations like some [sort of monster constructed from corpses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein%27s_monster).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Standard guidance lives here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. And always give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link to it.

In other words, identify the relevant bits of code, quote them, and then explain *in your own words* why they're relevant and useful in solving the problem at hand.

Comment: thx I will sit down and look over the post - I hope I can edit it to something worthy for this site.